# GeoWebCache tiles like chessboard

Tags: geoserver

We are generating cache from external WMS. In some zoom levels (17, 18 and up) all map is like chessboard, some tiles are ok but some tiles are just blank. When zooming in or out, different tiles are blank. We have tried to reseed, add the layer again, also add external WMS to Store again. We are out of ideas.

Map looks like this. Ok area surrounded by blank area.
[image]

No errors in logs. Tile size is 256x256. We generate tiles for EPSG:900913 jpeg. External WMS is ArcGIS. When we explore the map with QGIS, then external WMS seems to be ok.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Usually it means just that the remote WMS has sent a blank image as a response to GetMap. As a first aid you can search for very small png files from the cache and delete them. GeoWebCache will then make an new request when your users need that tile.

Comment: This seemed to be the problem. I found that Geoserver  had somehow generated lots of blank tiles. After removing them all seem to work well.  Thanks for help :)